# media screen syntax not working in my css

Tags: jquery, css

media screen not working. I don't know how do you this. Thank you for your help.

```css
#main {
         display: flex, inline-flex;
         a:-web-link-any {
            margin: 30px;
        }
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 1064px) {
          #main {
              a:-web-link-any {
                  margin: 30px;
              }
         }
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you expect to change? you write the same value in `margin` both times.

Comment: Sorry it is suppose to be 15px, I am using parent to child css so that inside the div main, the child html must change once the width changes.

Comment: Are you using LESS or CSS? Because they have different syntax rules

Comment: I am using all syntax in CSS form

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, Check the correct syntax

```css
#main {
     background:red;
display: flex, inline-flex;
     
}

#main a {
    margin: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1064px) {
      #main a {
              margin: 200px;
          }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So I don't have to do the parent child inherent?

Comment: yes you do but your syntax is incorrect check my code

Comment: I was planning to do this.

#main {
         display: flex;
         a {
             other formats
            margin: 30px;
         }
         .content {
            other formats
            margin: 40px;
         }
         .nav {
            background: blue;
         }
}

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
         #main {
                 a { 
                     margin: 15px;
                 }
                 .content {
                      margin: 25px;
                 }
} 

<div id=main>
       <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#">test</a>
       </nav>
       <div class="content">
           <p>Lorem djflajdlf kwljfe sdfjl</p>
       </div>
       <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

Comment: something like that but inherent doesn't work when at media. according to your code, I have to do this #main a or #main nav #main content #main button. It is tedious and repetitive.